# How to get query result from postgraphile running as a library

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, postgraphile

I have postgraphile running as an express middleware. For example:

```
const pgMiddleware = postgraphile(pool, SCHEMA, postgraphileConfig);

app.use(pgMiddleware);
```

How to get or intercept the result of a query or mutation without having a separate client?

For example when I send the below query

```
query {
 personById(id: 1){
  firstname
  }
}
```

I want to be able to get the data sent back inside the same express app. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are asking for is to be able to execute GraphQL operations against a PostGraphile schema from other routes/middlewares in Express without needing to make additional http requests. This is called [schema only usage](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-schema/) and you will specifically want to use [`withPostGraphileContext`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-schema/#api-withpostgraphilecontextoptions-callback) to execute your request and process results:

```js
import type { Express } from "express";
import type { Pool } from "pg";
import {
  gql,
  makeProcessSchemaPlugin,
  postgraphile,
  withPostGraphileContext,
} from "postgraphile";
import PgSimplifyInflectorPlugin from "@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector";
import type { GraphQLSchema } from "graphql";
import { graphql } from "graphql";

// Register your middlewares with express
const schemaOnlyUsageApp = (app: Express, pool: Pool) => {
  let schema: GraphQLSchema;

  // This plugin will execute a callback each time the PostGraphile
  // GraphQl schema is rebuit.
  const schemaProcessorPlugin = makeProcessSchemaPlugin((newSchema) => {
    schema = newSchema;
    return schema;
  });

  // Register the PostGraphile middleware as normal for requests on /graphql (and /graphiql)
  app.use(
    postgraphile(pool, "my_schema", {
      simpleCollections: "omit",
      dynamicJson: true,
      legacyRelations: "omit",
      setofFunctionsContainNulls: false,
      appendPlugins: [PgSimplifyInflectorPlugin, schemaProcessorPlugin],
      watchPg: true,
      graphiql: true,
      enhanceGraphiql: true,
      showErrorStack: true,
      allowExplain: true,
    })
  );

  // custom route that will execute a predefined gql query directly against the schema
  app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
    // arbitrary gql query
    const query = gql`
      query posts {
        posts {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
              body
              likeCount
              createdAt
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    const result = await withPostGraphileContext(
      {
        // Reuse your pool to avoid creating additional connections
        pgPool: pool,
      },
      async (context) => {
        // execute your query directly and get results without making
        // an additional http request!
        const queryResult = await graphql({
          schema,
          source: query.loc?.source || "",
          contextValue: { ...context },
        });
        return queryResult;
      }
    );

    res.send(result);
  });
};

export default schemaOnlyUsageApp;
```